# Elasticsearch: comparing dates (painless script)

Tags: java, elasticsearch, lucene, kibana, elasticsearch-painless

My **mapping** of `createdAt`:

```
"createdAt": {
    "type": "date"
},
```

I **insert** the dates like this:

```
POST logs/_doc/_bulk?pretty
{"index":{"_id":1}}
{"createdAt":"2018-05-01T07:30:00Z","value":"on"}
```

When I **request the documents**

```
GET logs/_doc/_search
```

It shows me the **date as I inserted** it:

```
"_source": {
    "createdAt": "2018-05-01T07:30:00Z",
    "value":"on"
}
```

Now I'd like to **compare this date with the current time**:

```
"map_script": {
    long timestampLog = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.S").parse(doc.createdAt.value).getTime();
    long timestampNow = new Date().getTime();

    if (timestampNow < timestampLog) {
        // case 1
    } else {
        // case 2
    }
}
```

**Weird:**
`doc.createdAt.value` returns `"2018-05-01T07:30:00.000Z"`, which **includes milliseconds that I never added**.

This **error occurs while parsing**:

```
Cannot cast org.joda.time.MutableDateTime to java.lang.String
```

When I replace `doc.createdAt.value` by the string `2018-05-01T07:30:00.000Z`, it works.

Any help is appreciated. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 4):

Elasticsearch index fields with date types are [`org.joda.time.DateTime`](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/userguide.html) in painless. Using the `SimpleDateFormat` is the source of the error.  Try this instead:

```
long timestampLog = doc['createdAt'].value.getMillis();
long timestampNow = new Date().getTime();
```

The rest works as is.

*Tested on Elasticsearch 6.3.0.*

Comment: Thank you. I will try again with your suggestion :)

Answer (score 1):

Please remove the **big** `S` in the `formatter`, check [Date and Time Patterns](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)

```
long timestampLog = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'hh:mm:ss").parse(doc.createdAt.value).getTime();
long timestampNow = new Date().getTime();
```

Comment: I just removed the `S` (`yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss`). The error is still the same. Any idea? Thank you!

Comment: Sorry I did not test it. Updated